# What is the foreign key if more than one pair of navigation properties exists?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The following is quoted from the official documentation.

> You can use the Data Annotations to configure how navigation
>   properties on the dependent and principal entities pair up. This is
>   typically done when there is more than one pair of navigation
>   properties between two entity types.
>
> ```
> public class Post
> {
>     public int PostId { get; set; }
>     public string Title { get; set; }
>     public string Content { get; set; }
>
>     public int AuthorUserId { get; set; }
>     public User Author { get; set; }
>
>     public int ContributorUserId { get; set; }
>     public User Contributor { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class User
> {
>     public string UserId { get; set; }
>     public string FirstName { get; set; }
>     public string LastName { get; set; }
>
>     [InverseProperty("Author")]
>     public List<Post> AuthoredPosts { get; set; }
>
>     [InverseProperty("Contributor")]
>     public List<Post> ContributedToPosts { get; set; }
> }
> ```

**Question**

As I am new to EF Core, what is the foreign key if more than one pair of navigation properties exist?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: It is too short to be understandable. Sorry.

Comment: Your question should to be reworded to *what **are** the foreign key**s** ...* - the Post class contains **two** FK - one for Author and one for Contributor

Comment: @SirRufo: I did not know that having 2 foreign keys is possible in a relationship between two tables.

Comment: There are n foreign keys possible between two tables (in theory - it is limited by the db system max field count per table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work in this way,

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Author")]
    public int AuthorUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Contributor")]
    public int ContributorUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Contributor { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Author")]
    public ICollection<Post> AuthoredPosts { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Contributor")]
    public ICollection<Post> ContributedToPosts { get; set; }
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Are you sure  attaching ` [ForeignKey("Author")]` attribute to `AuthorUserId` property rather than attaching ` [ForeignKey("AuthorUserId")]` to `Author` property?

Comment: Please recheck: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#foreignkey

Comment: Also you might not need the ForeignKey attribute at all if you have the Foreign Key Property Names like AuthorId and ContributorId. 
i.e. <Navigation_Property_Name>Id EF determine the foreign key by convention.

Comment: That might be another way of doing it. The way I suggested is the way we used to do it and I have many working codes.

Comment: OK.  Let other people confirm this in a couple of days.